# by pressing back button i want to reject android call

Tags: android, broadcast

I have a BroadcastReceiver and I know how to reject calls. But I need help rejecting a call when I press the back button, because I have some sort of error in my code...

```
public class CallReceiveD extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private ITelephony telephonyService;
    public String phoneNumber;
    public Bundle extras;
    public TelephonyManager tm; 
    public Intent i;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        i=intent;
        extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) 
        {
            String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
            {
                phoneNumber = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                Toast toast= Toast.makeText(context,phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);toast.show();
                tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
                try { 
                    Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName()); 
                    Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony"); 
                    m.setAccessible(true);

                    telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
                    // telephonyService.endCall(); 
                } catch (Exception e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        telephonyService.endCall(); 
        return;
    }   
}
```

My manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="denza12Des.call"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Call2BackActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".CallReceiveD">
            <intent-filter android:priority="99999">
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
      </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: As far I know the only thing where you can handle back button's click is in Activity (GUI). In broadcast.... I think you are out of luck..

Comment: override your onBackPressed method in Call2BackActivity.

Comment: A background app only can receive CAMERA and MENU keycodes, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I know you cant use the backbutton onreceive event that u are using to decline call, but the back button press function i ok and it should work if you use it other than in the broadcast receive onReceive